# Prove $\left|\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq |x|+|y|$

Tags: inequality

How can we prove that $\left|\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq |x|+|y|$?

I got this as homework but don't even know where to start.
I've tried developing $(x+y)^4$ but that didn't help to find a connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$, then we got $0\leq 0$ else $|\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4}|\leq |\frac{x^2y^3}{2x^2y^2}|\leq \frac{1}{2}|y|\leq |x|+|y|$

Comment: I actually have that solution separately. What I need to prove is that exact inequality somehow.

Comment: I don't see what you are looking for, this is a proof,isn't it ? (I'm sorry I'm french and my english is ugly :()

Comment: It is a proof indeed. The professor gave us this alternative answer,involving $\frac{1}{2}y$, which he proved, and asked us to proof the other one as homework.

Comment: What "other one," @GrozavAlexIoan? You have one problem here.

Comment: BTW, you need to handle specially the (obvious) cases of $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew : Absolutely, thanks. ( I'm new on this kind of forum but is it recommended to edit my answer ?)

Comment: @matovitch Definitely change your answer. The goal is for the best answer, not the first answer. :)

Comment: I meant the other way. With |x|+|y|. Anyway I worked something out. Thank you for your help!